# Impact printer that can handle PDFs well

Tags: pdf, printing

Need a dot matrix-style impact printer that can print a PDF.

Currently using a [MICROLINE® 321 Turbo](http://www.okidata.com/mkt/html/nf/SIDM.php?sku=ML320TSeries) with awful results. The fonts come out terrible unless I use super high quality, at which point the printer just goes over each line three times making everything too bold and almost blurry.

Yes, it's actually an 8 layer form from the Environmental Protection Agency called a Uniform Hazardous Waste Manifest. So what's happening is that its going over it so many times (it's almost treating the text on the PDF like an image) that it's making it blurry. If I don't use the highest DPI setting, the type is unreadable.

The app is a custom PHP application that's using TCPDF to create the PDFs. We used PDF because we thought it would be easier to line up text for the form.

Any suggestions? I wish I could use something other than PDF, but that's what my system outputs for reports.

Comment: Why do you require a dot matrix printer for this?

Comment: Probably for forms with multiple layers, IE: white copy on top, green below, and pink last. That is the most common use for these printers today.

Comment: What's the app? I only ask as I have been in this exact situation (output only going to PDF) and we did find some workarounds

Comment: @Linker3000 What were the workarounds? Right now, we're considering buying a much more expensive printer - that's the best idea we have.

Answer (score 1):

You could try an Epson DFX model if the volume is high, or try the updated model of the Oki - the ML420/ML421 series to see if that helps the speed.

Comment: The DFX series from Epson will be faster. However, to get best output it will still do multiple passes.